# $x$ is equal to at least $51$ of $a_1,\frac{a_1+a_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{100}}{100}$. Prove that $2$ of $a_1,\ldots,a_{100}$ are equal.

Tags: contest-math, average, pigeonhole-principle

> If $x$ is equal to at least $51$ number of the array $a_1, \frac{a_1+a_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{100}}{100}$, prove that $2$ numbers of the array $a_1,a_2\ldots,a_{100}$ are equal.

That's the way the problem is originally stated. It doesn't tell me whether *at least* or *exactly* $2$ numbers of the array $a_1,a_2\ldots,a_{100}$ are equal.

I've thought of a way to define the problem in a different way:

> If $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{100}$ is an array of distinct natural numbers that belong to the interval $[1\:;100]$ and $k\in\mathbb N$, $k\le50$ and
>   $\begin{cases}n_1x=a_1+a_2\ldots+a_{n_1}\\n_2x=a_1+a_2\ldots+a_{n_2}\\\ldots\\n_{50+k}x=a_1+a_2\ldots+a_{n_{50+k}}\end{cases}$, prove that $2$ numbers of the array $a_1,a_2\ldots,a_{100}$ are equal.

I have no idea at the moment how we could come up with a proof that $2$ numbers of the array $a_1,a_2\ldots,a_{100}$ are equal. Some ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: if 51 of the numbers are equal, then two consecutive ones must be equal. That seems as if it might lead somewhere, and it uses the pigeonhole principle, which seems likely to be where this problem arises.

Comment: In problems where you have to prove that at least some number are equal, pigeonhole principle is a great tool.

BTW, yes, it means "at least 2." If it didn't mean at least 2, then consider that all of the terms are equal (since the problem says at least 51), then $a_1=a_2=a_3=\dots=a_{100}$, so more than $2$ are equal. If it said "exactly 2," we could stop there and say that it is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

Let $b_i$ denote the $i$th term of the sequence.

By pigeonhole principle, at least two consecutive terms $b_n, b_{n+1}$ are equal.

If $n$ is even, then necessarily at least one other pair of consecutive terms are equal. If $b_k, b_{k+1}$ are equal, then it can be shown that $a_{n+1} = a_{k+1}$

If $n$ is odd, then it can be that $b_n, b_{n+1}$ is the only pair. If it wasn't, then we can conclude similarly as above. So consider $b_n, b_{n+1}$ being the only pair. $b_1 = a_1$ must be one of the terms equal to $x$ (the terms equal are $a_1 = a_3 = \dots = a_n = a_{n+1} = a_{n+3} = \dots = a_{100}$). Furthermore, $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n}{n} = \frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_{n+1}}{n+1}$, so $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots+a_n}{n} = x$. Thus, $a_{n+1} = a_1$. $\blacksquare$

Btw, do you know where this problem is from? Seems like a 1990s USAMO problem.

Comment: I've searched for it on the website https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/USAMO_Problems_and_Solutions
But it doesn't seem to contain this problem (I mean the 1990th year). Oh, you meant the 1990s, not the 1990th.

Comment: This looks like the best answer to me.

Comment: Do you really need to treat $n$ even and $n$ odd as two separate cases?

Comment: Although it is quite obvious that there must be two consecutive and equal values $b_i$, it is not so obvious to make this an instance of the pigeonhole principle. If you think of it, here is a way: partition $\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$ into $50$ disjoint sets $\{2i-1,2i\}$, then one pair must contain two of the indices$~n$ with $b_n=x$ by the pigeonhole principle. But this means you get the reduction to the case $n$ odd for free. (One must still do all of the reasoning above for that case.)

Answer (score 5):

Let $I$ be the set of all $0 \le n \le 100$ such that $x_1 + \cdots + x_n = nx$.
Note that $0$ does belong to $I$, and so do the $51$ (or more) other values stated in the hypothesis, so $|I| \ge 52$.

Since $I$ is a subset of $\{0, \ldots, 100\}$ with size at least $52$, it must contain at least **two** pairs of consecutive elements.  In other words, there are distinct $m,n$ such that $m, m+1\in I$ and $n, n+1 \in I$.  (One way to see this cleanly is to consider the spacings between the first $52$ elements: there are $51$ spaces totaling at most $100$, so at least two of the spacings must be $1$ rather than $\ge 2$.)

Notice that whenever $r,r+1 \in I$ we have that $a_{r+1} = x$ (since you're confused you may want to double-check that this holds for $r=0$, but it really is the same calculation as any $r$).  Thus with $m$ and $n$ chosen as above, we have $a_{m+1} = a_{n+1} = x$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. (But your answer could do with some clarification.)

Comment: But I haven't defined $a_0$, so why have you defined $n$ as $0\le n\le 100$? If $n=0$, then what is $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n$ equal to? The indexes are all greater than $0$. I don't understand this.

Comment: @mathh This is extremely standard notation.  The sum from $n=1$ to $0$ is the empty sum, namely $0$.

Comment: I still don't understand why you've shown that $n$ can be equal to $0$. The set $a_1,\frac{a_1+a_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{100}}{100}$ clearly shows $n$ is $1,2,\ldots,100$. What use does it make to have that $n$ is $0$ if it clearly can't be in this case. I don't understand this.

Comment: @mathh Clearly, when $n=0$ the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_n = nx$ holds since both sides are equal to $0$.  Therefore, $0$ is always in the set $I$.

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$A=\{\,k\in\mathbb N_0\mid k\le 100,a_1+\ldots+a_k=kx\,\}.$$ 
Then $A$ contains not only the 51 given indices, but trivially also $0\in A$, i.e. $|A|\ge 52$.
Let $B= (\mathbb N\setminus A)\cap (A+1)$. Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B\subseteq \{0,1,\ldots,101\}$ imply $$\tag1|A|+|B|\le 102.$$ For each  $k\in (A+1)\cap A$ we have $1\le k\le 100$ and $$ a_k=(a_1+\ldots+a_k)-(a_1+\ldots a_{k-1})=kx-(k-1)x=x.$$
Now 
$$(A+1)\cap A=(A+1)\setminus(\mathbb N\setminus A)=(A+1)\setminus B $$
and $$ |(A+1)\setminus B|\ge |A+1|-|B|=|A|-|B|\ge 2|A|-102\ge 2$$
Shows that there are at least two indices $k$ with $a_k=x$.

Comment: It's  not like Hagen made it up. That is the proper notation.

Comment: How can you define that $k$ can be equal to $0$? Isn't it apparent that it arranges between $1$ and $100$? Since I haven't defined the number $a_0$. I don't understand this.

Comment: What does $|A|$ define? Cardinality of the set $A$?

Comment: I've added my own solution which I believe works if you don't want to decipher his comment.

$|A|$ does indeed denote the cardinality of the set.

Answer (score 3):

One can say slightly more, not only two of those $a_i$ are equal, actually two of them equal $x$.

Clearly if two consecutive running averages are equal to $x$, then the term added in the second running average was equal to $x$. One obviously cannot select $51$ out of $100$ running averages without this happening at least once (every selected average except the last would block its successor from selection, which gives $50\times2+1$ selected or blocked averages, one too many). If it actually happens more than once, then we have got our two instances of $a_i=x$. But if one wants it to happen just once, then  by a similar argument, every one of the $100$ running averages is either selected or the successor of a selected average, the two conditions being satisfied simultaneously just once. But that means the very first running average was selected, making $a_1=x$, which together with the instance $a_i=x$ for the index $i$ that was both selected and the successor of a selected index gives our two instances.

One can avoid the case distinction by adding a running average $0$ declared to be equal to $x$ (with which the argument "two consecutive averages equal to $x$ implies the second $a_i=x$" remains valid), and argue for at least two pairs of consecutive chosen averages. This is essentially the [answer by Eric Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651172/18880). I just wanted to show that one arrives at the conclusion also using only rather fantasy-less reasoning.